# Draw a road network in java?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I want to develop a road traffic simulating system. But I don't have a clear idea about how should I represent the road network. The requirement is to draw the road map using google maps. So what I think is, if I can get lat & lon from google map(set of lat & lon to represent a link), then I can draw the roads converting lat & lon to x,y coordinates. I hope if I have x,y coordinates then I can represent links and nodes in java, is it possible? Please can someone guide me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you have a reasonable idea with which to start.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11509483/194609

Answer (score 3):

It's not a Java problem; you'd have to do this in every language.

You need to map (lat, lon) to your screen/zoom window (x, y) as a starter.

You could start with a graph data structure where the nodes are locations or intersections and the links are roads.  Once you have that, worry about the display issues - think "MVC".

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am using a graph, vertices as junctions and edges as roads. The edges contains the distance between the connected vertices(Junctions). I'm trying to model the road traffic in my system. So I want to graphically show the road network(with moving cars- I haven't think about this yet). Is there any tools I can use? Please guide me